# WP7 - Isolated Storage settings wiped on "Rebuild"

Tags: windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I just discovered (the hard way) that if you deploy your application to a device after doing a "Rebuild" or a "Clean -> Build" from Visual Studio your app is first uninstalled and then reinstalled resulting in the isolated storage files being wiped.

The Application Deployment Tool always seems to do uninstall - reinstall irrespective of whether it was an incremental build or not.

Has anybody found a workaround to this? Of course, the most obvious one is never to rebuild your application, but what if you accidentally do? Currently, I don't have all the generated files under source control, so if I were to try to build the app on another computer it would be a rebuild (maybe I will add all the generated junk into source control if no one has a workaround)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I can suggest an alternative appraoch.. I think you will find it beneficial in other situations as well if you can introduce a little process to the generation of your test data so that it is easier to either a) restore or b) generate.

You could for example have a debug build only feature to upload/download the files on the device to a wcf service running locally on your PC (a simplified version of what Rongchaua did [here](http://rongchaua.net/blog/windows-phone-phone-pc-connector-through-wcf-service/)).

Or, more work, if you are willing, but offering even more additional benefits would be to develop some automated testing capability into your app.. starting with generation of initial test data. Here's something you could look at to get started on that path.

[Claus Konrad Blog: WP7: How to unit test a MVVM Light WP7-application](http://blog.clauskonrad.net/2010/11/wp7-how-to-unit-test-mvvm-light-wp7.html)

Granted these would take a bit of effort, but it's an approach that gives you some independence from manually generated test data, which in my experience invariably turns out to be a hassle at various times. And once solved, you find all sorts of reasons to thank yourself for doing it later.. whether it be saved time, or more robust testing because you can afford to be more aggresive with your test data/test execution and manage multiple test data configurations.

Comment: The WCF service thing looks interesting, can it be used to transfer files to/from a real device or just the emulator? The problem with the second approach is that I didn't use MVVM Lite in my app, just wrote my own viewmodels, so it might be a bit of work to get that integrated right now. Is there a lot of benefit to using the MVVM Lite framework?

Comment: I recommend watching Laurent Bugnion's EX14 from mix. You will get a quick understanding of what MVVM brings to the testability equation. Yes, that app will work with a device provided your device has network access to your PC whether through USB or net exposed http service. It needs updating from CTP though, or just read the code for ideas.

Comment: I'll definitely be looking into both of those recommendations. But for the interim, do you know what VS files I should add to revision control so I can restore those and make VS think its not a clean rebuild?

Comment: It shouldn't be hard to work out. Make a small change, copy the folder, do a rebuild in one and a build in the other, then use software the likes of BeyondCompare to compare the two folders for what's different besides the obvious object files that were recompiled. You may find yourself renaming the xap's to zip and doing this exercise on the contents of that too.

Comment: No, of course it isn't hard to figure out, just tedious. I was hoping for the easy way out :)

Comment: @MickN - Link to Claus Konrad's blog is broken.

Answer (score 3):

There is a a workaround:

- open the solution configuration manager
- next to build is a deploy column, uncheck your project
- press F5

This will launch the app that is already on the device without overwriting it (and deleting its storage).