# Saved files deleted after creating a new build

Tags: windows-phone-8, build, save, unity-game-engine

I have a level editor in my game, which saves the generated levels to a single file. It works as it should when used normally, but whenever I build to my phone (WP8, Nokia Lumia 620), the existing files are deleted. I also save options (currently just vibrate on/off and sound volume) and high scores in a similar way, which causes them to be reset every time I build.

I'm saving the file as a .txt at Application.persistentDataPath.

I have checked and confirmed that Application.persistentDataPath remains the same after building the new version.

When I publish the app, and later decide to release an update, would the files then get removed as well? Or is it only when I'm building? Is there any way to prevent the files from getting deleted?

I have tested on Android where it works perfectly.

Comment: A similar question was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697678/wp7-isolated-storage-settings-wiped-on-rebuild

Comment: This will not effect published apps, just local apps deployed through VS